# Facebook like button stripping some URL fragments

Tags: url, fbml

I have several facebook "like" buttons on the same page which link to anchors of that page. They're specified like this:

```
<div class="fb">
    <fb:like href="<?php echo $share_url; ?>" 
             send="false" layout="button_count" 
             width="90" show_faces="false" 
             font="lucida grande"></fb:like>
</div>
```

where `$share_url` is like `http://mikaelareuben.com/food/#some-anchor`. The majority of the like buttons work fine, however some of them get the `#some-anchor` part stripped off, so the like button just links to `/food`.

Some of the fragments that get dropped are:

- `#kale-arugula-pine-nut-salad`
- `#cumin-coleslaw`
- `#roasted-red-pepper-and-avocado-salad`

etc. There is nothing that I can see that is different from ones that aren't lost:

- `#green-gazpacho-with-avocado-cream`
- `#butternut-squash-soup`

etc. The examples of missing fragments I listed are the first three like buttons rendered on the page, but there are others which come after like buttons which work properly.

I've tried replacing the `#` with `%23` to no avail.

This issue can be replicated [straight on the page that gives you like button codes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/): just enter `mikaelareuben.com/food/#cumin-coleslaw` and note that when clicking the button it shows `mikaelareuben.com/food` in the flyout. Then enter `mikaelareuben.com/food/#butternut-squash-soup` and notice how it works properly.

What the heck is going on here?

## Edit

`#butternut-squash-soup` no longer works! It's like there's some kind of blacklist at play here? I have no clue.

Comment: The like button uses different URLs to identify different resources. Different Anchors do not make URLs different from one another. So basically you are giving the same URL all the time.

Comment: But it works fine for some and not for others. It's not even just the like count - the URI in the flyout sometimes has the fragment, And sometimes has it stripped out deliberately